# Why are the structure fields coming empty?

Tags: matlab

When I am accessing the structure fields like s(1).'fieldname' it's coming back empty. Only the last value can be seen, i.e s(97).'fieldname'. This is my code:

```
clc;
clear all;
data1= load('mydata.txt');
a=1;n=1;count=1;m=0;
while (count<98)                           % main loop starts
    for i=a:a+1023
        mydata1(i-m*1024)=data1(i);        % taking 1k points in mydata1
    end
    m=m+1;
    newdata=10*log10(abs(fft(mydata1)));   % taking fft in newdata from mydata
    for j=1:512
        newdata1(2*j-1)=newdata(j);        % interpolation of newdata to newdata1
        newdata1(2*j)=newdata(j);          % newdata1 size is 1024
    end
    a=j*n+513;
    n=2*count+1;
%     plot(newdata1);
%     pause(1);                            % setting threshold
    th=18;
    newdata2(newdata1<th)=0;               % newdata2 has 1024 0s and many 1s 
    newdata2(newdata1>=th)=1;
    num=0;
    for k=1:1023                           % loop for reducing many 1s
        if((newdata2(k)==1)&&(newdata2(k+1)==1))
        num=num+1;
        end
        if(num>0 && (newdata2(k+1)==0 || k==1023))
            for p = k-num:k
                newdata2(p)=0;
            end
            p= (k-num)+floor(num/2);
            newdata2(p)=1;
            num=0;
        end                                % loop ends
   end
   newdata2(1024)=0;                       % newdata2 with only 1s and 0s
   binnum = find(newdata2);
   x=length(binnum);
   frequency=((100000/1024)*binnum);
   for y=1:x
       strength(y)=(newdata1(binnum(y)));
   end
   s= struct;                              % writing into a structure
   s(count).frame=count;
   s(count).freq=frequency;
   s(count).str=strength;
   count=count+1;
end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `s= struct;  %writing into a structure` is creating a new structure variable each iteration of the `while` loop. Either move this line outside the loop, or omit it completely.